# JSON Object incorrect and causing HttpException

Tags: java, json, servlets, httpexception

I'm trying to test this method:

```java
private ServiceApiMetadata getConfig(final HttpServletRequest request, final String path)
    throws IOException {
  final Schema schema;
  try (final InputStream inStream = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream(path)) {
    final JSONObject origSchema = new JSONObject(new JSONTokener(inStream));
    if (isGoldStar()) {
      origSchema.getJSONObject("properties")
          .getJSONObject("notifications")
          .getJSONObject("properties")
          .getJSONObject("topic")
          .put("pattern", "^[0-9A-Za-z-.]*$");
    }
    schema = SchemaLoader.load(origSchema);
  }

  final ServiceApiMetadata config;
  try (final BufferedReader reader = request.getReader()) {
    final JSONObject json = new JSONObject(new JSONTokener(reader));
    schema.validate(json);
    config = ServiceApiMetadata.read(json);
  } catch (final ValidationException e) {
    _logger.debug(e.getMessage());
    if (e.getLocation().contains("#/properties/notifications")) {
      throw new ServiceApiException(ServiceApiError.MALFORMED_NOTIFICATIONS_ERROR,
          ServiceApiErrorMessage.MALFORMED_JSON);
    } else {
      throw new ServiceApiException(ServiceApiError.MALFORMED_JSON);
    }
  } catch (final JSONException e) {
    _logger.debug(e.getMessage());
    throw new ServiceApiException(ServiceApiError.MALFORMED_JSON);
  }

  return config;
}
```

As it's private I created the following method in my class:

```java
@TestOnly
protected void runGetConfig(final HttpServletRequest request, final String schemaPath) throws IOException {
  final ServiceApiMetadata conf = getConfig(request, schemaPath);
}
```

When I run my test `getConfig()` throws an exception. The problem is that when line `final JSONObject json = new JSONObject(new JSONTokener(reader));` I get this exception:

```
HttpException(400,{"status_code":400,"error_code":"MalformedJson","uri":"uri","message":"MalformedJson"},null)
```

I also see this error in my log:

```
at 0 [character 1 line 1]
```

For the HttpServletRequest I'm using `org.springframework.mock.web.MockHttpServletRequest.MockHttpServletRequest()` as follows:

```java
final MockHttpServletRequest request = new MockHttpServletRequest();
```

Is it possible this is creating an incorrect `reader` which in turn means the `JSONObject` is incorrect and if so how do I resolve this?

**Additional info**
I added a body to the `MockHttpServletRequest` but the issue is still the same. I added some logging as can be seen below:

```java
final JSONObject rawSchema = new JSONObject(new JSONTokener(inputStream));
      _logger.info("rawSchema: " + rawSchema);
      if (isPulsar()) {
        rawSchema.getJSONObject("properties")
            .getJSONObject("notifications")
            .getJSONObject("properties")
            .getJSONObject("topic")
            .put("pattern", "^[0-9A-Za-z-._:/]*$");
      }
      schema = SchemaLoader.load(rawSchema);
    }

    final ServiceApiContainerMetadata conf;
    try (final BufferedReader reader = request.getReader()) {
      _logger.info("reader: " + reader);
      _logger.info("JSONTokener(reader): " + new JSONTokener(reader.readLine()));
      final JSONObject json = new JSONObject(new JSONTokener(reader.readLine()));
```

It shows me this in the output:

```
rawSchema: {VALID JSON STRUCTURE. IT'S TOO BIG TO INCLUDE IN THIS QUESTION}
reader: java.io.BufferedReader@4c4d27c8
JSONTokener(reader):  at 0 [character 1 line 1]
```

**Info on MockHttpServletRequest**

The body of my `MockHttpServletRequest` contains the Lorem ipsum text. If I add the following code below my BufferedReader that text is printed to console. That same text is also used in ``final JSONObject json = new JSONObject(new JSONTokener(reader.readLine()));`so the malformed JSON error in my`HttpException` is no surprise.

```java
while ((strCurrentLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {
  _logger.info("reader: " + strCurrentLine);
}
```

Could this be a bug in my code? Should `final JSONObject json = new JSONObject(new JSONTokener(reader.readLine()));` in fact be `final JSONObject json = new JSONObject(schema);`? If I try that I can get see the code now reaches `schema.validate(json);` but there are `12 schema violations found`. I can't see what these are though. Another thought is should the body be JSON?

I updated the body to JSON which resulted in 2 validation errors. One was that `service_id` was missing and `testkey` was present so I resolved that and my method no longer throws an exception when I use `final JSONObject json = new JSONObject(new JSONTokener(reader));`.

Comment: print out the JSON and run it through https://jsonlint.com/ and see why your Json is malformed.

Comment: What else do you inititialize your MockHttpServletRequest with? Did you set its body?

Comment: No @GreyFairer. What/how do I do that?

Comment: I'm now setting a body but still experience the same issue. I've added some logging which I'll detail in my question.

Comment: To resolve this I added a notifications key to my body JSON. This allowed `final JSONObject json = new JSONObject(new JSONTokener(reader.readLine()));` to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To resolve this I added a `notifications` key to my body JSON. This allowed `final JSONObject json = new JSONObject(new JSONTokener(reader.readLine())); to work`.

Answer (score 0):

If you do just `request = new MockHttpServletRequest();` then the request will have no body and the reader will not have data.

You can use MockMvcRequestBuilders to create a complete request.

```
request = MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/message")
  .contentType(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
  .content("{... json body ...}")
  .buildRequest(context);
```